# Trigger PubSub event in firebase emulator from CLI

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-tools

According to this webpage it is possible to trigger a pubsub event from the CLI on an instance in the cloud
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

```sh
gcloud pubsub topics publish topic-name --message '{"name":"Xenia"}'
```

is it possible to trigger a pubsub even with the cli on the pubsub firebase emulator?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure whats on mind .... what exactly means "this"? and what exactly you mean by "firebase emulator"? Can you add more details about the use case? what do you want to test?

Comment: @vitooh I edited the question: is it possible to trigger a pubsub even with the cli on the pubsub firebase emulator?

Comment: I have reviewed all available documents and haven't found any information how to use Firebase Pub/sub emulator. We can only find that it exists. I think you should raise it as a bug or feature request on [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report). There is as well Google pubsub [emulator in Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator). Maybe you will be able to use it.